# Já é possível fazer aplicativos comerciais com o Visual C++ Cross Platform?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mobile, xamarin, cross-platform

O Visual Studio 2015 trouxe consigo o Visual C++ Cross Platform, que pelo que me parece funciona de forma similar ao Xamarin.

Já é possível fazer aplicativos comerciais com o Visual C++ Cross Platform?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sim, já é possível. Mas provavelmente você vai preferir usar o Xamarin.

C++ e C# são as únicas linguagens, até a data da resposta, que rodam nas três principais plataformas mobile (considerando que Symbian já é legado, e ok, hoje já são duas, Windows já não é uma opção viável).

C++ é uma linguagem mais difícil e preferida apenas quando se precisa de muita performance, fazer aplicações em tempo real e acesso direto ao hardware (e não através de API). Para mobile C++ tem a vantagem de economizar bateria. Mas o custo do desenvolvimento é alto. Mesmo com uma equipe experiente com C++, deve-se pensar se vale a pena investir nisto.

Além disto apenas a linguagem roda em todas as plataformas. O código para cada uma delas poderá ser aproveitando parcialmente, mas o acesso à API de cada uma delas terá que ser feito manualmente. Não tem facilidades. Pelo contrário, dependendo da plataforma, o acesso à API pelo C++ é bem complicada. E até limitada. É verdade que a [Qt](https://www.qt.io/) ajuda muito nisto.

Xamarin não é uma linguagem. É uma plataforma de desenvolvimento que além da linguagem C#, tem uma biblioteca que abstrai as duas principais plataformas mobile e o código pode ser reaproveitado quase totalmente.

<strike>Pegue o Xamarin e seja feliz. Mesmo que ganhe muito pouco, em algumas semanas de trabalho, ele se paga. Antes de aprender 10% do C++ ele já se pagou. Nem vou falar da economia por não ter que desenvolver mais de uma vez. No tempo que vai dar os primeiros passos só para entender isto, você faz um trabalho extra, ganha um dinheiro e compra o Xamarin. Essa ideia de que software gratuito torna o desenvolvimento mais barato é muito errada. Software que dá produtividade é que torna mais barato.</strike> Nada disto vale mais, agora ele é gratuito.

E tem bastante artigo sobre o assunto em uma simples busca no Google. Em inglês, mas nunca conheci alguém quem programa (de verdade) em C++ e não soubesse inglês.

Hoje existem outras opções.