# Xamarin é completamente grátis?

Tags: xamarin, licença

Alguém sabe dizer se em algum momento é preciso pagar por usar o xamarin? Se mesmo desenvolvendo apps gratuitos é preciso pagar?

Caso seja um app que faça parte de um serviço, porém o app é grátis, é preciso de alguma licença ou algo do gênero?

O Unreal Engine por exemplo é grátis, porém uma parte do lucro obtido com o software desenvolvido com ele deve ser repassado a Epic Games, com o xamarin existe algo assim?

Comment: Relacionado, talvez alguma seja duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/90871/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/35337/101, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91525/101 e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/152242/101

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não completamente. Ele é parte do Visual Studio agora, então, se você tem uma licença do Visual Studio poderá usar o Xamarin.

O Visual Studio Community é grátis e pode ser usado por desenvolvedores individuais, desenvolvedores de projetos *open-source* (para o desenvolvimento destes projetos), projetos/pesquisas acadêmicas, para fins educacionais e empresas com um time de desenvolvimento pequeno.

Se você se encaixa em um destes itens, então **sim, o Xamarin é grátis pra você**.

Você pode ver mais sobre o uso do Visual Studio/Xamarin Community em

- [Visual Studio Community pode ser usado em projetos comerciais?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40609/18246)
- [Termos de licença para software Microsoft](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547)
- [Termos de licença para software Xamarin](https://www.xamarin.com/license)

Answer (score 6):

https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-for-all/

Uma parte que é interessante:

**Visual Studio agora inclui o Xamarin.**

Xamarin vai estar em todas as versões do Visual Studio (a partir da data do post), incluindo na versão Community (provavelmente a mais usada), que é grátis para desenvolvedores individuais, projetos open-source, pesquisas acadêmicas, propósitos educacionais e times profissionais pequenos.

Você pode desenvolver e publicar aplicativos iOS e Android feitos com C# ou F# diretamente com o Visual Studio,  sem limites de tamanho de app.

No link tem muito mais informações, vale a pena dar uma olhada.

Comment: O VC Community não é igual ao Enterprise. Veja o comentário na pergunta.

Comment: @bigown Pelo que entendi da resposta, ele refere-se à versão do Xamarin e não ao Visual Studio.

Comment: Mas não é exatamente igual. O Enterprise tem mais coisas do Xamarin.