# O que é Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin

Parece que o Xamarin é muito novo. Dizem que você pode desenvolver android ou IOS ou Windows Phone pelo C#. É isso mesmo ?

Pra quem está começando agora, vale a pena ou não ?

Comment: Relacionada: [Desenvolver para várias plataformas usando C# e Xamarin Studio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38099/desenvolver-para-várias-plataformas-usando-c-e-xamarin-studio)

Comment: Relacionada²:[Xamarin é completamente grátis?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210633/xamarin-é-completamente-grátis)

Comment: Veja a wiki da tag [Xamarin](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/xamarin/info).

Answer (score 1):

Exatamente, você programa em C# e ele "converte" em um App Android e iOS.

Tem suas vantagens, uma delas por não precisar saber 2 linguagens (java ou kotlin para Android e Swift para iOS) e criar um App para as duas plataformas.

Também as desvantagens, por exemplo não ter tantas possibilidades de customizacoes no design do App, e ser 100% nativo, podendo ou não ter alguma perda na performance.

Existem muitas matérias disso, o xamarim não é tão "novo" assim, mas melhorou bastante desde seu lançamento.

Comment: Complementando o que o colega disse, veja esse link: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/